# Using gitlab to deploy spring cloud microservices using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, spring-cloud, gitlab-ci-runner

After researching about different CI i decided to use Gitlab to build and deploy my application which is a set Spring boot applications using Spring cloud.
I have installed Gitlab on prem. on our build server and installed gitlab-runner  on test-server which is running the application inside docker.
unfortunately the test server doesnt have access to internett and i cant build application by maven. I am a bit confused on how i can use gitlab to build and deploy my project.

Right now i do the building manually in following steps

On my pc

1. Build the project by `mvn clean install`
2. Build docker images by `docker-compose build`
3. Push the docker images to docker-hub with `docker-compose push`

on the test server

4. pull images from docker-hub `docker-compose pull`
5. run application in docker `docker-compose up`

What is the best approach to use gitlab on my project?